# How to write automated tests for SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, testing, regression-testing

The current system we are adopting at work is to write some extremely complex queries which perform multiple calculations and have multiple joins / sub-queries.  I don't think I am experienced enough to say if this is correct or not so I am agreeing and attempting to function with this system as it has clear benefits.

The problem we are having at the moment is that the person writing the queries makes a lot of mistakes and assumes everything is correct.  We have now assigned a tester to analyse all of the queries but this still proves extremely time consuming and stressful.

I would like to know how we could create an automated procedure (without specifically writing it with code if possible as I can work out how to do that the long way) to verify a set of 10+ different inputs, verify the output data and say if the calculations are correct.

I know I could write a script using specific data in the database and create a script using c# (the db is SQL Server) and verify all the values coming out but I would like to know what the official "standard" is as my experience is lacking in this area and I would like to improve.

I am happy to add more information if required, add a comment if necessary.  Thank you.

Edit: I am using c#

Comment: Are the queries you want to test run from a C# program or are they run by hand or something else?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth They are run within a C# web application. So the final output at the moment is an html table from the original query.

Comment: Just to clarify... are you trying to test the correctness of an application that generates/uses queries?  And basically test if those queries correctly reflect some externally-specified business rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard approach to testing code that runs SQL queries is to unit-test it. (There are higher-level kinds of testing than unit testing, but it sounds like your problem is with a small, specific part of your application so don't worry about higher-level testing yet.) Don't try to test the queries directly, but test the result of the queries. That is, write unit tests for each of the C# methods that runs a query. Each unit test should insert known data into the database, call the method, and assert that it returns the expected result.

The two most common approaches to unit testing in C# are to use [the Visual Studio unit test tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264975.aspx) or [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/). How to write unit tests is a big topic. [Roy Osherove's "Art of Unit Testing"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890) should be a good place to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question to state I am using c#.  We have no current system for automated tests on a c# level either so I need all advice in this area as well.

Comment: I will mark the question as correct as you have given me a direction to go into and no-one else seems to have a response which is better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this question, while generally correct for testing *code*, does not address the issue of testing your database at all.

It sounds like you're after [database unit tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29). The idea is that you create a temporary, isolated database environment with your desired schema and test data, then you validate that your queries are returning appropriate data.

Comment: archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20140331215306/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt.aspx